# How to correctly use PrismJS and its typings with typescript / angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building a little app with **angular-cli** and I would like to use **PrismJS** but I can't get it work.

So basically I've created a **vendor** folder where I put my Prism's scripts and styles and load them in the **index.html**.

I also need to install type definitions in order to be able to compile my app :

```
npm i --save-dev @typings/prismjs
```

Then, I just have to call `Prism.whatever()` anywhere in my code but this doesn't work.

Even my IDE doesn't recognize the namespace `Prism`.

By checking the content of the definition (`index.d.ts`) I've seen that since version 1.6, it doesn't contain

```
declare var Prism : PrismJS.Prism;
```

anymore. There is just some `export namespace Prism`. So I was wondering if I have to import something since any `declare` is used.

It seems weird to me to import something from a definition file.

As I wanted to step over this, I've installed an older version of the definition (1.4.16) which contains

```
declare var Prism : PrismJS.Prism;
```

Now, my IDE (webstorm) is happy! It can recognize `Prism`. But when I try to compile, webpack still outputs an error:

```
Cannot find name 'Prism'
```

So my question is pretty basic: what have I forgotten?

*Sorry for this obvious question.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

in angular-cli add prism.js like that:

```
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/prismjs/prism.js"
],
```

after that, you can make typescript happy with

```
declare var Prism;
```

and use it like that

```
<code [innerHtml]="myCode"></code>

ngAfterViewInit() {
   const code = 'var data = 1;';
   this.myCode = Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.javascript);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid `  declare var Prism;`. Still, this is my actual setup.

Answer (score 8):

I think you have done -

1. `npm install prismjs -S`
2. `npm install @types/prismjs -D`

now you need to import it ithe n component as -

```
import * as prism from 'prismjs';
```

and then use `prism.whatEverMethod()` which prism js supports

Answer (score 4):

I would like to extend the previous answers with the ability to use other languages besides the default ones. 
At first, install Prism with `npm i prismjs`.

In your `angular.json` add:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/prismjs/prism.js"
]
```

In your component import the necessary languages:

```
import 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-css';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-javascript';
// ...you can import further languages aswell

declare var Prism: any;
```

See [here](https://prismjs.com/#supported-languages) for all available languages.

Finally, apply the code highlighting:

```
code: string = 'helloWorld() { console.log("hello world"); }';
languageIdentifier: string = 'typescript';

ngOnInit() {
    this.code = Prism.highlight(this.code, Prism.languages[this.languageIdentifier]);
}
```

in the template:

```
<code [innerHtml]="code"></code>
```

Comment: just a note, you dont have to import and include in scripts, either or. I import `import Prism from 'prismjs';` then added the line `import 'prismjs/components/prism-css';` for missing languages of the default, and it works (not sure if it is properly tree shaken though). but  yes, I spent a day trying to import a missing language :/ so thank you

Answer (score -1):

I've tried angular-prism and ng2-prism without success (but was my bad maybe?).

You might want to add to add the code inside ngAfterViewInit inside a setTimeout to not trigger the "Expression has changed after it was checked." error.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       const code = 'var data = 1;';
       this.myCode = Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.javascript);
    }
}
```

also in html this is more correct if you wnt it to be displayed correctly:

```
<pre><code [innerHtml]="myCode" class="language-csharp"></code></pre>
```